# Symfony1 doctrine:migrate - The application "cache" does not exist

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, migration

I have a Symfony1 application, which I haven;t touched for a while. I have created some database changes as a migration and want to apply them with

```
./symfony doctrine:migrate
```

On my server environment I get an error message

```
The application "cache" does not exist.
```

I have never seen this before. I also had a look at the migration task in the doctrine plugin, but can't find it anywhere. I also can't reproduce it on my development system.

Any idea how to diagnose this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to launch other command? What does a `symfony cc` says? Did you run `symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff` before?

Comment: Sorry I never answered these. SYmfony cc works fine, doesn't help. generate migrations diff shows the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a folder "cache" under the apps directory. Removing this resolved the problem.